# Downloading arrays off cur.fetchall() in Python and Oracle 11g

Tags: python, sql, oracle11g, tuples, fetchall

I'm trying to download a single array off of Oracle 11g into Python using the cur.fetchall command.  I'm using the following syntax:

```
 con = cx_Oracle.connect('xxx')
 print con.version
 cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select zc.latitude from  orders o, zip_code zc where o.date> '24-DEC-12'     and TO_CHAR(zc.ZIP_CODE)=o.POSTAL_CODE")
latitudes = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
print latitudes
```

when I print latitudes, I get this:

```
[(-73.98353999999999,), (-73.96565,), (-73.9531,),....]
```

the problems is that when I try to manipulate the data -- in this case, via:

```
x,y = map(longitudes,latitudes)
```

I get the following error -- note, I'm doing the same exact type of syntax to create 'longitudes':

```
TypeError: a float is required
```

I suspect this is because cur.fetchall is returning tuples with commas inside the tuple elements.  How do I run the query so I don't get the comma inside the parenthesis, and get an array instead of a tuple?  Is there a nice "catch all" command like cur.fetchall, or do I have to manually loop to get the results into an array?

my full code is below:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('xxx')
print con.version
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select zc.latitude from  orders o, zip_code zc where     psh.ship_date> '24-DEC-12' and TO_CHAR(zc.ZIP_CODE)=o.CONSIGNEE_POSTAL_CODE")
latitudes = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select zc.longitude from  orders o, zip_code zc where psh.ship_date> '24-DEC-12' and TO_CHAR(zc.ZIP_CODE)=o.CONSIGNEE_POSTAL_CODE")
longitudes = cur.fetchall()
print 'i made it!'
print latitudes
print longitudes
cur.close()
con.close()
map = Basemap(resolution='l',projection='merc',         llcrnrlat=25.0,urcrnrlat=52.0,llcrnrlon=-135.,urcrnrlon=-60.0,lat_ts=51.0)
# draw coastlines, country boundaries, fill continents.
map.drawcoastlines(color ='C')
map.drawcountries(color ='C')
map.fillcontinents(color ='k')
# draw the edge of the map projection region (the projection limb)
map.drawmapboundary()
# draw lat/lon grid lines every 30 degrees.
map.drawmeridians(np.arange(0, 360, 30))
map.drawparallels(np.arange(-90, 90, 30))
plt.show()
# compute the native map projection coordinates for the orders.
x,y = map(longitudes,latitudes)
# plot filled circles at the locations of the orders.
map.plot(x,y,'yo')
```

Answer (score 1):

The trailing commas are fine that is valid tuple syntax and what you get when you `print` a tuple.

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but map is probably not what you want.  map takes a function and a list as arguments but you are giving it 2 lists.  Something more useful might be to retrieve the latitude and longitude from the database together:

```
cur.execute("select zc.longitude, zc.latitude from  orders o, zip_code zc where o.date> '24-DEC-12'     and TO_CHAR(zc.ZIP_CODE)=o.POSTAL_CODE")
```

### Update to Comments

From the original code it looks like you are trying to use the built-in `map` function which is not the case from your updated code.

The reason you are getting the `TypeError` is matplotlib is expecting a list of floats but you are providing a list of one tuples.  you can unwrap the tuples from your original latitudes with a simple list comprehension (the map built-in would also do the trick):

```
[row[0] for row in latitudes]
```

Using one query to return the latitudes and longitudes:

```
cur.execute("select zc.longitude, zc.latitude from...")
points = cur.fetchall()
longitudes = [point[0] for point in longitudes]
latitudes = [point[1] for point in latitudes]
```

Now `longitudes` and `latitudes` are lists of floats.

Comment: To further explain, I'm using Basemap to plot latitudes and longitudes over a map of the US.  here's my whole code:

Comment: I've put my whole code above, but basically I'm trying to plot orders geographically. I've had no problem in the past passing two arrays into map() via x,y=map(array1, array2) so I suspect that isn't the problem.  Please correct me if I'm wrong though.  If you think that retrieving latitude and longitude together makes more sense, could you please show how I would pass this into map() and then map.plot()?

Comment: I copied your code verbatim, but when I print out 'latitudes' and 'longitudes' i get:

Comment: I copied your code verbatim, but when I print out 'latitudes' and 'longitudes' i get:  [], i.e. the arrays are not filled. Am I missing something? I had to define latitudes and longitudes as arrays to avoid error: the name is undefined.   Here's the new code:   
    import cx_Oracle
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('xxx')
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select zc.latitude, zc.longitude...")
    points = cur.fetchall()
    longitudes=[]
    latitudes=[]
    longitudes = [point[0] for point in longitudes]
    latitudes = [point[1] for point in latitudes]
    cur.close()
    con.close()

Answer (score 0):

Found another way to tackle this -- check out [TypeError: "list indices must be integers" looping through tuples in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046621/typeerror-list-indices-must-be-integers-looping-through-tuples-in-python).  Thanks for your hard work in helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and one work around is to clean up the commas from the tuple elements in a loop as you mentioned (not so efficient though), something like this:

```
cleaned_up_latitudes=[] #initialize the list
for x in xrange(len(latitudes)):
    pass
cleaned_up_latitudes.append(latitudes[x][0]) #add first element
print cleaned_up_latitudes
```

> > [-73.98353999999999, -73.96565, -73.9531,....]

I hope that helps.