# TypeError: "list indices must be integers" looping through tuples in python

Tags: python, oracle, oracle11g, tuples

I'm a python newbie, so hopefully this question can be easily answered.

I'm pulling a tuple from Oracle 11g, and then want to create matrices from it with a for loop.  However, I'm getting an error that  says:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

What am I doing wrong?  Code is below:

```
import cx_Oracle
con = cx_Oracle.connect('xxx')
print con.version
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("select zc.latitude, zc.longitude from  orders o, zip_code zc where     o.ship_date> '24-DEC-12' and TO_CHAR(zc.ZIP_CODE)=o.CONSIGNEE_POSTAL_CODE")

output = cur.fetchall()
cur.close()
con.close()

latitudes=[]
longitudes=[]

for i in output:
    latitudes[i]=output[i][0]
    longitudes[i]=output[i][1]
```

the end result I want is splitting the tuple into two arrays, one with latitudes and one with longitudes.

Comment: You're not pulling a tuple, you're pulling a list of tuples...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looping over the result rows, not a series of numbers. Use `.append()` to add items to `latitudes` and `longitudes` instead:

```
for i in output:
    latitudes.append(i[0])
    longitudes.append(i[1])
```

The `for` loop takes each item of `output` and assigns it to the variable `i`, so `i` is a result row tuple, not an integer. It might be easier to understand if you renamed the variable:

```
for row in output:
    latitudes.append(row[0])
    longitudes.append(row[1])
```

If your result rows contain only 2 columns per row, you can also use a `zip()` trick to split out the columns into separate lists:

```
latitudes, longitudes = zip(*output)
```

`*output` means: apply each element from `output` as a separate argument to the `zip()` built-in function, so `zip()` is called with `zip(output[0], output[1], output[2], ...)`. `zip()` takes each element from those individual rows, and combines those into new output lists. Two columns per row means `zip(*output)` produces two output lists.

Comment: Might also be worth mentioning `enumerate` if, for some reason, it's important to have the indices as well.

Comment: @MattTenenbaum: not with the empty `latitude` and `longitude` lists; since you cannot use indices on empty lists, it's not going to be easy to fit `enumerate()` into a working example here.

Answer (score 2):

You are confused about how a Python `for` loop works - it loops over objects, not indices, so you are getting the tuples and trying to use them to index the list.

Fortunately, what you are trying to do is actually far easier if you use [the `zip()` builtin](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip), which does exactly what you want:

```
latitudes, longitudes = zip(*output)
```

`zip()` can be thought of as taking rows of data and returning columns - it returns the first item of each input iterable, then the second, etc... E.g:

```
>>> list(zip([1, 2, 3], ["a", "b", "c"]))
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

This happens to be exactly what you want. In this case, we use the `*` operator to unpack `output` as the input iterables.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in output:
    latitudes[i]=output[i][0]
    longitudes[i]=output[i][1]
```

should be...

```
for tup in output:
    latitudes.append(tup[0])
    longitudes.append(tup[1])
```

Because the things you get when you loop over a list of tuples are individual tuples, not indices in the list.

However, as Lattyware mentions, you can simply `zip()` your outputs instead.